# Shared Preferences  Cannot resolve method "getPreferences"

Tags: android-sdk, android, java

Здравствуйте.
Столкнулся с такой проблемой: не получается в нужном месте прочитать настройки.
В активити я писал вот такой код, который работает

```
    myPrefs = getPreferences(MODE_PRIVATE);
    String user_guid = myPrefs.getString("guid", "")
```

Теперь я создаю класс и в одном из методов пытаюсь прочитать настройки,

```
     public static List<User> getUserFromServer(final String s) throws IOException, JSONException {

    myPrefs = **getPreferences**(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);// **Cannot resolve method "getPreferences"**
    String user_guid = myPrefs.getString("guid", "");

    myPrefs.getString("guid", "");

    final String url = URL_PREFIX + QUERY_GET_USER;
    final List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairList = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("query", "spr_employee_get"));
    nameValuePairList.add(new BasicNameValuePair("p_guid", user_guid));
    final String resp = execHttpGet(url, nameValuePairList);
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(resp);
    if (jsonObject.has("p_result")) {
        if (jsonObject.getString("p_result").equalsIgnoreCase("ok"))
            return JsonWorker.jsonToUserList(jsonObject.getJSONArray("p_item").toString());

    }
    return new ArrayList<User>();
}
```

В интернете толком ничего не нашёл.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Передать в метод ссылку на Activity:

```
public static List<User> getUserFromServer(Activity a, final String s) throws IOException, JSONException {
 myPrefs = a.getPreferences(Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
...
```

Answer (score 4):

Метод `getPreferences()` является методом класса `Activity`, а вы его пытаетесь применить в статическом методе, где отсутствует `this`, который видимо и является `Activity`. Передайте параметром `Activity` или как то еще донесите экземпляр `Activity`, чтобы от него взять `Activity.getPreferences()`

Comment: @Barmaley ♦ хочу написать статический метод получения данных из настроек. Посмотрите код?

          public static String getGuid() {

        SharedPreferences myPrefs;
        Activity a = new Activity();

        myPrefs = a.getSharedPreferences("p_guid", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        String guid = myPrefs.getString("guid", "");
        return guid;
    }